# What is 'input.map' in google apps script (custom spreadsheet function) example?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm confused by this example from Google's [Apps Script Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization). This function iterates over given range and performs a computation on each cell.

```
function DOUBLE(input) {

  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(DOUBLE); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    return input * 2;
  }

}
```

Things I don't understand:

1. What object is the `input` in this function? `typeof` tells me it is a number, but shouldn't it be an array? It is after all a range of values (e.g. A2:B).
2. What is the `.map` thing after the `input` variable? I cannot find it in the [reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). It is also not highlighted, as variables or functions are.
3. The purpose of the conditional statement is unclear to me. Does `return input.map(DOUBLE)` mean "do whatever you find in the corresponding `else` statement over the whole array"? Why is it structured like so?

Any insights (or pointers to the right sources) much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is an example of using introspection to conditionally execute the code. `if (input.map)` will return truthy if input is an Array (and has a `map` function) and will return falsy in all other cases.

This code is therefore testing to see whether input is an Array and if not, it is treating it as a number, otherwise it is treating it as an Array.

You can see the definition of the map function on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Best book to learn about JavaScript is "JavaScript the Good Parts" [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1419857713&sr=8-1&keywords=javascript+the+good+parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)